# Concatenate string using the Excel Macro

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a scenario where i need to concatenate the rows of 1 column. For this i was trying to create a Macro. However , when i am using the formula its throwing the application defined error. Below is the code

```
Sub ABCS()
Dim U
Dim str As String
Set myArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

lastrow = ws.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastrow
For i = 1 To lastrow

str = Cells(i, 1).Value

Cells(2, 2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & str & ")"

Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is you looking for...

```
Sub ABCS()
    Dim U
    Dim str As String
    Set myArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    lastrow = ws.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox lastrow
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        str = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Final = Final & str
    Next i
    Cells(2, 2) = Final
End Sub
```

Another way to do the concaetenation is as below. Here we can directly call in the specific cell with the concaetenation Range (see the image below).

```
Public Function concaetenateme(r As Range) As String
    Dim str As String
    For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count
        str = r.Cells(i)
        Final = Final & str
    Next i
    concaetenateme = Final
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this way its works, but i wanted how this can be done using formula.
Thanks! anyway

Comment: that means you want to do this in cell? do the above code in public function and call in the cells you want. Kindly mark as answer if you fulfill with this code

Comment: @anuvratsingh, see the updated code. Kindly mark this as solution, if you are satisfy with my code